# Шапки на новый год

Tags: поддержка, новогодние-шляпы

Если я получу шапку на новый год, она останется у меня навсегда? Или после празднований ее у меня отберут?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Согласно [FAQ](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/faq) шапка исчезает 9го января.
Это просто праздничное развлечение, а не постоянное дополнение к сайту.

Comment: жапь, думал будет красоваться у меня всегда)

Comment: @Maxgmer ну Вы всегда можете сохранить картинку с шапкой и ручками поменять свой аватар.

Comment: @Maxgmer, кроме того некоторые люди ненавидят шапки, специально для них есть даже кнопочка которая их отключает

Comment: Странные люди))

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка, это не совсем так. Шапка рисуется поверх аватарки и может выходить за пределы её области. С картинкой так не выйдет.

Comment: **Было бы хорошо, если бы можно было надеть заработанные шапки на следующее празднование** или, как минимум, оставить в профиле, чтобы можно было видеть что заработано и что можно заработать на следующее празднование, чтобы эта трата времени была не разовая и от неё был ощутимый эффект.